# Where can I get some work done in Salzburg, Austria? (WiFi + power outlet)

Tags: work, power, wifi, salzburg

I need to do some work during my travels. I see many cafes such as Cafe Bazar and Würfel Zucker offering free WiFi, but I don't know whether they'll have power outlets, and I need somewhat of a guarantee on having power.

I'm open to any suggestions—cafes, libraries, other public areas including train stations (granted there are definitely power outlets), etc. A cafe would be ideal so I feel like I'm still on vacation :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About cafes and such:
A generally valid answer if a cafe has outlets near the tables won´t be possible, but nobody will have a problem if you just ask. More than "yes, there and there" or "no" won´t happen.
[This site](http://www.salzburg.info/de/service/salzburg_fuer/internetsurfer?PageSpeed=noscript) lists some cafes, restaurants etc. with free WIFI:

> Afro Cafe, Bürgerspitalplatz 5
>   Altstadt Hotel Garni Trumer Stube, Bergstraße 6
>   Altstadthotel Amadeus, Linzer Gasse 43-45
>   Arthotel Blaue Gans / Blaue Gans Bar, Getreidegasse 41-43
>   Café Balthazar, Kaigasse 31 (Täglich von 11:00 bis 23:00 Uhr)
>   Café Erhards, Nonntaler Hauptstraße 16
>   Coffee Symphony, Griesgasse 13
>   Café Universum, Hofstallgasse 4
>   Hotel Altstadt Radisson Blu, Rudolfskai 28
>   Hotel Mönchstein, Mönchsbergpark 26
>   Hotel Stein / Steinterasse, Giselakai 3-5
>   Indigo, Rudolfskai 8
>   McDonald‘s, Getreidegasse 26
>   Murphy’s Law, Gstättengasse 33
>   republic Café, Anton-Neumayr-Platz 2
>   Restaurant m32, Mönchsberg 32
>   Stadtwirt, Schwarzstraße 10
>   The Heart of Joy Café, Franz-Josef-Str. 3

Libraries are more reliable. Salzburgs biggest one (Neue Mitte Lehen) has free WIFI too,
and I would be *very* surprised if they have no power outlets for visitors.

If everything else fails (I won´t believe it even if you say so), another (a bit questionable) idea:
The University surely has places to work outside of courses.
*(Well, "one of the two Universities". There is a separate one for art stuff).*
You´re not a student, but nobody is going to notice....

Answer (score 5):

How about [Coworking Salzburg](http://coworkingsalzburg.com/)? They rent coworking space for as little as 25`EUR` (as of writing), including a desk, power outlets and Wi-Fi. The location is not exactly central, but to be fair coworking spaces rarely are.